# If no callback is specified when asynchronously loading gmaps the other necessary google map scripts aren't loaded

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is this documented somewhere that I need to specify a callback in order for the google.maps module to be defined?  Or is this a bug.

The following code doesn't load the google maps module:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Asynchronous Map Simple
    </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 8,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            myOptions);
      }

      function loadScript() {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.6&key=myKey&sensor=false'   //adding  'callback=something' gets the maps module to load
        document.body.appendChild(script);
      }

      window.onload = loadScript;
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Edit -- response to answer

> To do so, you can inject your own  tag in response to a
>   window.onload event or a function call, but you need to additionally
>   instruct the Maps JavaScript API bootstrap to delay execution of your
>   application code until the Maps JavaScript API code is fully loaded.
>   You **may** do so using the callback parameter, which takes as an argument
>   the function to execute upon completing loading the API.

How does that imply that not having a callback will not load any of the api?  It says that you can use the callback parameter to execute a function when the code if fully loaded but it doesn't say the code will never load without a callback parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It is documented here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html#asynch

Comment: The wording may be a little odd, but it seems pretty clear to me that you must specify the callback parameter. It's a very common pattern for asynchronously loading scripts.

Comment: Well if they said must instead of may, I wouldn't be posting this question.  They enforce the sensor parameter and alert the developers if one isn't specified it would be nice to have the same functionality with another "required" parameter.  This is sounding like a bug to me.

Comment: The sensor param being required is just silly to me. The difference here is that it is the same URL used to load the API asynchronously or synchronously through a normal script tag in the page. The synchronous method does not require the callback but the async method does, so it can't be enforced.

Comment: Your link is no longer valid.